# Using GOTO for a FSM in C

Tags: c, goto, state-machine

I am creating a finite state machine in C.
I learned FSM from the hardware point of view (HDL language). So I'm used a `switch` with one `case` per state.

I also like to apply the Separation of Concerns concept when programing.
I mean I'd like to get this flow:

1. Calculate the next state depending on the current state and input flags
2. Validate this next state (if the user request a transition that is not allowed)
3. Process the next state when it is allowed

As a start I implemented 3 functions:
    static e_InternalFsmStates fsm_GetNextState();
    static bool_t fsm_NextStateIsAllowed(e_InternalFsmStates nextState);
    static void fsm_ExecuteNewState(e_InternalFsmStates);

At the moment they all contain a big switch-case which is the same:

```
switch (FSM_currentState) {
case FSM_State1:
    [...]
    break;
case FSM_State2:
    [...]
    break;
default:
    [...]
    break;
}
```

Now that it works, I'd like to improve the code.

I know that in the 3 functions I'll execute the same branch of the switch.
So I am thinking to use `goto`s in this way:

```
//
// Compute next state
//
switch (FSM_currentState) {
case FSM_State1:
    next_state = THE_NEXT_STATE
    goto VALIDATE_FSM_State1_NEXT_STATE;
case FSM_State2:
    next_state = THE_NEXT_STATE
    goto VALIDATE_FSM_State2_NEXT_STATE;
    [...]
default:
    [...]
    goto ERROR;
}

//
// Validate next state
//
VALIDATE_FSM_State1_NEXT_STATE:
    // Some code to Set stateIsValid to TRUE/FALSE;
    if (stateIsValid == TRUE)
        goto EXECUTE_STATE1;
    else
        goto ERROR;

VALIDATE_FSM_State2_NEXT_STATE:
    // Some code to Set stateIsValid to TRUE/FALSE;
    if (stateIsValid == TRUE)
        goto EXECUTE_STATE2;
    else
        goto ERROR;

//
// Execute next state
//
EXECUTE_STATE1:
    // Do what I need for state1
    goto END;

EXECUTE_STATE2:
    // Do what I need for state2
    goto END;

//
// Error
//
ERROR:
    // Error handling
    goto END;

END:
    return; // End of function
```

Of course, I could do the 3 parts (calculate, validate and process the next state) in a single switch case. But for code readability and code reviews, I feel like it will be easier to separate them.

Finally my question, is it dangerous to use GOTOs in this way?
Would you have any advice when using FSM like that?

Thank you for your comments!

---

After reading the answers and comments below, here is what I am going to try:

```
e_FSM_InternalStates nextState = FSM_currentState;
bool_t isValidNextState;

//
// Compute and validate next state
//
switch (FSM_currentState) {
case FSM_State1:
    if (FSM_inputFlags.flag1 == TRUE)
    {
        nextState = FSM_State2;
    }
    [...]

    isValidNextState = fsm_validateState1Transition(nextState);

case FSM_State2:
    if (FSM_inputFlags.flag2 == TRUE)
    {
        nextState = FSM_State3;
    }
    [...]
    isValidNextState = fsm_validateState2Transition(nextState);
}


//
// If nextState is invalid go to Error
//
if (isValidNextState == FALSE) {
    nextState = FSM_StateError;
}


//
// Execute next state
//
switch (nextState) {
case FSM_State1:
    // Execute State1
    [...]

case FSM_State2:
    // Execute State1
    [...]

case FSM_StateError:
    // Execute Error
    [...]
}

FSM_currentState = nextState;
```

Comment: No problem with `GOTO`. Don't be fanatic-anti-goto.

Comment: While I'm not an anti-goto-fanatic, I really think that you should avoid it in this case: You're writing a switch statement, but you don't want to write the code inside it ... so why not using functions, instead of random goto inside the body of your own function ?

Comment: One specific problem here is than when you end up at `ERROR:` you have absolutely no idea where you came from - so what error do you handle? Also, if `goto END` really means `return`, why not just use `return`?

Comment: @NiBZ: I wanted to avoid a call to a function since I am mainly using global variables. That is why I wanted to use GOTOs. But no matter what I'll do, I realized that I'll have 2 switch. One to validate the transition and one to "execute the state". So in the end, using GOTOs won't be that efficient... So I'll create one "validate" function per state and I'll call them for the switch. Thank for your comment!

Comment: @BoPersson: It was not said I my question but I have globals variables so I can handle the errors almost everywhere. And the END label was more a "do some stuff and return" than just a "return" :)!

Comment: @Plouff - The collected experience with global variables and goto is that suddenly one of the variables is wrong, and we cannot tell where it got that value. When debugging this we often miss a came-from operator to follow the chain of gotos. Not recommended!

Comment: @BoPersson: Thank you for this recommendation! I will definitely not using GOTOs if it can lead to such problems! What do you think of the update I proposed?

Comment: Comment on the edit only: Please do not compare with `true`. Just use `if ( input.button1 ) ..` and use adjectives as names. That way your code reads more naturally. I normally do not use explicit validation functions. If the inputs fail the `if .. else if ..` chain for the next-state transition`, it is automatically invalid. As you write it, you cannot even validate inputs if you allow N:1 state-transitions. I think I wrote that in my answer; please comment if that was not clear enough.

Comment: @Olaf: Btw, I use `== TRUE` since bool is not a type in C and so `true` and `false` are not defined by the language but they are defines that we have. If the define is wrong (#define TRUE 0) then the code won't work... I feel like I tend to be "oversafe" when I read your comments.....

Comment: `bool` is **very well** a standard type in C. Actually it is `_Bool`, but normally you [`#include <stdbool.h>`](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#B.17) which provides macros with the C++-names mapped to the standard names. Even for outdated pre-C99 compilers, any value `!= 0` will be treated as `true`, so unless you have a `FALSE` other than `0` (if really never should have!), it still behaves as expected. I actually do not know any language where such a comparison is recommended practice.

Comment: Oh!!!! I am going to try right now. I found the stdbool.h of the compiler for our microcontroller. It's a nice added value of this post for me :)!!! Thank you again!

Comment: @Plouff: If you can use C11 (the current standard), you will get some more benefits for embedded, just read the link I posted. But even with C99 you might find things like VLAs or flexible array members quite interesting. I'd recommend to read a more recent book than K&R, and/or browse the internet.

Comment: @Olaf: Unfortunately the compiler (TI) doesn't support C11 they only implemented a subset of C99. I am going to have a look at VLAs and flexible array members :). Thanks for those pointers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `goto` has its benefits in C, it should be used sparesly and with extreme caution. What you intend is no recommendable use-case.

Your code will be less maintainable and more confusing. `switch`/`case` is actually some kind of "calculated" goto (thats's why there are *case **labels***).

You are basicaly thinking the wrong way. For a state-machine, you should first verify input, then calculate the next state, then the output. There are various ways to do so, but it is often a good idea to use two switches and - possibly - a single error-handling label or a error-flag:

```
bool error_flag = false;

while ( run_fsm ) {
    switch ( current_state ) {

        case STATE1:
             if ( input1 == 1 )
                 next_state = STATE2;
             ...
             else
                 goto error_handling;   // use goto 
                 error_flag = true;     // or the error-flag (often better)
             break;

        ...
    }

    if ( error_flag )
        break;

    switch ( next_state ) {

        case STATE1:
            output3 = 2;
            // if outputs depend on inputs, similar to the upper `switch`
            break;
        ...
    }

    current_state = next_state;
}

error_handling:
    ...
```

This way you are transitioning and verifying input at once. This makes senase, as you have to evaluate the inputs anyway to set the next state, so invalid input just falls of the tests naturally.

An alternative is to have an `output_state` and `state` variable instead of `next_state` and `current_state`. In the first `switch` you set `output_state` and `state`, the second is `switch ( output_state ) ...`.

If the single `case`s become too long, you should use functions to determine the `next_state` and/or `output_state`/outputs. It depends very much on the FSM (number of inputs, outputs, states, complexity (e.g. one-hot vs. "encoded" - if you are family with HDL, you will know).

If you need more complex error-handling (e.g. recover) inside the loop, leave the loop as-is and add an outer loop, possibly change the error-flag to an error-code and add another switch for it in the outer loop. Depending on complexity, pack the inner loop into its own function, etc.

Sidenote: The compiler might very well optimize the structured approach (without `goto`) to the same/similar code as with the `goto`

Comment: Thank you for this answer! That is almost what I was about to implement regarding the answer I had. I am going to post what I am going to try. Could you tell if it is a good idea? Thank you!

Comment: I understand what you mean now. Like you said, I am not thinking in this way! My way of viewing the FSM is: 1/ Reading the flags to know where the system wants to go. 2/ Determine if the system is allowed to go where it wants to. Moreover, I was considering that: if I have no request, I stay in the same state (I updated the first lines of my 2nd code above). So I can't fall in error state that easily at the moment. I think I need to review my whole point of view on my FSM!

Comment: @Plouff: I also know VHDL/hardware design, so I can very well understand you viewpoint. It helps to keep in mind that HDL/hardware treats the signals parallel (possibly pipelined, but still), while in software you are working sequential. You might have thought about the `goto`s as some kind of intermediate signal. But it soon will become very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

Whether it is "dangerous" is probably somewhat a matter of opinion.  The usual reason people say to avoid GOTO is that it tends to lead to spaghetti code that's hard to follow.  Is that an absolute rule?  Probably not, but I think it's definitely fair to say that it is the trend.  Secondarily, most programmers at this point are trained to believe that GOTO is bad, so, even if it's not in some case, you may run into some level of maintainability issue with other people coming into the project later.

How much risk you have in your case, probably depends on how big of a chunk of code you're going to have under those state labels and how sure you are that it won't change much.  More code (or potential for large revisions), means more risk.  In addition to just straight questions of readability, you'll have increased chances for assignments to variables interfering between cases or being dependent on the path you took to get to a certain state.  Using functions helps with this (in many cases) by creating local scope for variables.

All in all, I would recommend avoiding the GOTO.

Comment: Combining your answer and NiBZ's comment above I am not going to use GOTOs and use functions in my big switch instead. The maintainability with other people is also another argument not to use them. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need to use switch-case, it will actually get optimized away by the compiler into machine code with a function pointer jump table. Switch-cases for state machines tend to be somewhat hard to read, especially the more complex ones.

The spaghetti-gotos are unacceptable and bad programming practice: there are a few valid uses of `goto`, this is *not* one of them.

Instead, consider to have a one-line state machine which looks like:

```
state = STATE_MACHINE[state]();
```

Here is [an answer of mine](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/96415/6102) (taken from the electrical engineering site, it pretty much applies universally) which is based on a function-pointer lookup table.

```
typedef enum
{
  STATE_S1,
  STATE_S2,
  ...
  STATE_N // the number of states in this state machine
} state_t;

typedef state_t (*state_func_t)(void);


state_t do_state_s1 (void);
state_t do_state_s2 (void);

static const state_func_t STATE_MACHINE [STATE_N] =
{
  &do_state_s1,
  &do_state_s2,
  ...
};


void main()
{
  state_t state = STATE_S1;

  while (1)
  {
    state = STATE_MACHINE[state]();
  }
}

state_t do_state_s1 (void)
{
  state_t result = STATE_S1;
  // stuff
  if (...) 
    result = STATE_S2;
  return result;
}

state_t do_state_s2 (void)
{
  state_t result = STATE_S2;
  // other stuff
  if (...) 
    result = STATE_S1;
  return result;
}
```

---

You can easily modify the function signatures to contain an error code as well, such as for example:

```
typedef err_t (*state_func_t)(state_t*);
```

with functions as

```
err_t do_state_s1 (state_t* state);
```

in which case the caller would end up as:

```
error = STATE_MACHINE[state](&state);

if(error != NO_ERROR)
{
  // handle errors here
}
```

Leave all error handling to the caller as show in the above example.

Comment: Hmm, It depends on the complexity of the FSM, number of inputs, etc. If I might recommend, I'd use designated initializers for the table with the state-names. That way you do not have to count/comment entries and cannot forget one if adding/removing states. I'd also put the table after the functions to avoid adding the prototypes.

Comment: @Olaf For complex cases you can always create some generic parameter type (like for example the one passed to thread callback functions in any thread library). Designated initializers might be a good idea, I'm assuming you mean something like `STATE_MACHINE [STATE_N] = {  [SUPER_CRITCAL_STATE] = &handle_super_critical_state, ... }` ?

Comment: @Lundin: Thank you for sharing this nice snippet. It is a bit too complicated for me at the moment. I am switching from HDL to Embedded Software (after a period in OOP), that is why I'd like to keep a form that looks like what I was used in HDL! But your way of seeing the FSM is really interesting. Thank you again!

Comment: @Plouff My advise is to forget that you ever saw HDL, it is so extremely low-level that it barely counts as programming :) Things such as good programming practice are non-existent in that language. This example is actually not that advanced, if you only understand function pointers. Copy/paste it into a compiler and play around with it!

Comment: @Lundin: I agree that HDL is not programming. I learned other languages too (SystemVerilog [OOP], Python, C++, etc.) and now C. So fortunately, I know what a function pointer is :). The problem is that I update the FSM every 1ms. So I evaluate the next state every 1ms. So I can't use you snippet has is. When I would execute a do_state_sN, I won't be able to compute the next state at the end of the function! That is why I said it was interesting to see this way of implementing a FSM :).

Comment: @Lundin: I just think there is no single good recipe for "the" FSM, but the best solution depends. For instance, your approach might be faster or slower on some architectures, if speed is an issue (interrupt handlers), etc. No criticism. "I'm assuming you mean ..." Yes, exactly.

Comment: @Plouff: VHDL, Verilog, etc. have a very different paradigm, due to their inherent parallelism. Lundin is right about "forgetting" them (or always keeping the difference in your mind). However, it's not clear what the problem is with Lundins approach. If you ahve 1ms "ticks", you have to be ready within this time anyway, no matter which approach you actually use.

Comment: I have a 1ms tick. At the beginning of the tick I compute and execute the "next state". Then for the rest of the tick, *things may happen* during interrupts (communication, emergency stuff, etc.) and set flags for the FSM. Depending on those flags, I'll determine the next state at the beginning of the next tick. But now I know what I am going to do. I'll use Olaf's approach in terms of transitioning and validating next state. Then I'll use Olaf's array of do_states to execute the states code without switch statement. I hope it'll do!!

Comment: @Plouff All this code does in regards to timing is to execute faster than what you currently have. You are not obliged to calculate the next state from inside the states, it is just an example. As long as you set the state  after some kind of policy, preferably at one single place in the code. State machines that set and checks states all over the place tend to become buggy and unmaintainable.

Comment: @Plouff Also, the case you describe is by no means unique, sounds like your average embedded system, which is actually what this code was written for. Add a timer to it and you'll pretty much end up with a crude version of a RTOS.

Comment: @Lundin: Regarding your 1st comment. That's exactly my POV. The different modules of the system will set (and read) flags for (from) the FSM. So that I can evaluate the next state in one place according to the flags no matter where they come from (flags are grouped in bit fields) **in one place**. Regarding your 2nd comment, that actually what we have. We use a timer to "schedule" the tasks. The "scheduling" is a run to completion defined at compilation time (we just launch the tasks every Nms). Thanks again :).

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb is to use GOTOs only to jump forward in the code, but *never* backwards. In the end this boils down to using GOTO *only* for exception handling, which otherwise doesn't exist in C.

In your particular case I would absolutely not recommend the use of GOTO.

Comment: If found the same rule here:
http://blog.smartbear.com/development/goto-still-has-a-place-in-modern-programming-no-really/
Thanks!

Comment: While this rule of thumb is sound and I fully agree with it, it does not answer the question.