# One hot encoding of the states of a C FSM

Tags: c, state, state-machine

Basically, I just would like to know if this is a good idea to manually one hot encode the states of a C FSM.
I implemented that to write an easy state transition validator:

```
typedef enum
{
    FSM_State1 = (1 << 0),
    FSM_State2 = (1 << 1),
    FSM_State3 = (1 << 2),
    FSM_StateError = (1 << 3)
} states_t;
```

Then the validation:

```
states_t nextState, requestedState;
uint32_t validDestStates = 0;

// Compute requested state
requestedState = FSM_State1;

// Define valid transitions
validDestStates |= FSM_State2;
validDestStates |= FSM_State3;

// Check transition
if (validDestStates & requestedState)
{
    // Valid transition
    nextState = requestedState;
}
else
{
    // Illegal transition
    nextState = FSM_StateError;
}
```

I know that I am limited to the maximum size of integer that I can use. But I don't have that many states. So it is not an issue

Is there something better than this encoding?
Are there some drawbacks I don't see yet?

Thanks for your help!

*Edit: changed validation test according to user3386109 comment*

---

### Final thoughts

So final here is what I did:

1/ State enum is a "classical" enum:

```
typedef enum
{
    FSM_State1,
    FSM_State2,
    FSM_State3,
    FSM_StateError
} states_t;
```

2/ Bit fields for valid transitions:

```
struct s_fsm_stateValidation
{
    bool State1IsValid: 1;
    bool State2Valid: 1;
    bool State3IsValid: 1;
    bool StateErrorIsValid: 1;

    /// Reserved space for 32bit reserved in the union
    uint32_t reserved: 28;
};
```

3/ Create an union for the validation

```
typedef union FSM_stateValidation_u
{
    /// The bit field of critical system errors
    struct s_fsm_stateValidation state;
    /// Access the bit field as a whole
    uint32_t all;
} u_FSM_stateValidation;
```

4/ I changed the validation:

```
u_FSM_stateValidation validDestStates;

// Set valid states
validDestStates.state.State1 = true;

// Compute requestedState
requestedState = FSM_State2;

if ((validDestStates.all & ((uint32_t) (1 << requestedState)) ))
{
    // Next state is legal
    return requestedState;
}
else
{
    return FSM_StateError;
}
```

Comment: As long as you are aware of the limitations i don't see anything wrong with a system like this. In fact I think it should be well-suited for a small state-machine in very small embedded environments, where space is at a premium.

Comment: I think is a question for [CR](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @meaning-matters You need `&` not `|`,  e.g. `if (validDestStates & requestedState) nextState = requestedState;`.

Comment: "Is there something better than this encoding?" Define better. Faster, safer, less memory consuming? What is your reason to use bits in the first place? If it is because you need a fast evaluation of valid state transitions, this method is slightly faster than using an up-counting integer for the states. If you need fast calls to the actual states, this method is slightly slower, because you can't use a function pointer-based lookup table, nor can the compiler translate your swich statement into one.

Comment: (Regarding lookup tables see [the discussion we had yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32182876/using-goto-for-a-fsm-in-c/32184665#32184665))

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: The "small state-machine in very small embedded environment" is exactly what I am doing :)!

Comment: @user3386109: Thanks for the improved validation.

Comment: @Lundin: I am now using a switch to define the next state, and then your array of doState() functions to execute the state. So if understand all the comments and compared to upcounting integer for the states, I'll loose time to reach the current state and I save time during state validation. The new information for me is the *I loose time to reach the current state*. So like you said, I need to identify what is the most important for me!

Comment: @Plouff The lookup table is based on adjacent numbers from 0 to N. If you don't have adjacent numbers, such as in the case of this bit version, you'd have to translate the bit to an index, or similarly use a switch statement which the compiler won't be able to effectively optimize. It is probably not going to cause any big performance issues in most applications, where you don't need to concern yourself about such micro-optimizations.

Comment: @Lundin: Yes, I just realized that.... It's a shame the C language doesn't define hash tables!

Comment: @Lundin: Finally I came up with a new solution. I keep an easy state validation and I can now use your lookup table :)!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a quick Google, "one hot encoded" means that every valid code has precisely one bit set, which seems to be what you're doing. The search results suggested this was a hardware design pattern.

Drawbacks I can think of are...

1. As you suggest, you're dramatically limiting the number of valid codes - for 32 bits you have a maximum of 32 codes/states instead of more than 4 billion.
2. It's not ideal for lookup tables, which are a common implementation for `switch` statements. There are usually an intrinsic available to determine which is the lowest bit set, but I wouldn't bet on compilers using that automatically.

Those aren't big issues, though, provided the number of states is small.

The question IMO, then, is whether there's an advantage to justify that cost. It doesn't need to be a huge advantage, but there has to be some kind of point.

The best I can come up with is that you can use bitwise tricks to specify sets of states, so you can test whether the current state is in a given set efficiently - if you have some action that needs to be done in states `(1<<0)` and `(1<<3)`, for example, you could test `if (state & 0x9)`.

Comment: Yes, I have a hardware designer background. This is where I learned one hot encoding in state machines. I was not aware of the second drawback you mention. That is the kind of remarks I was looking for. Your last point is very interesting too. Not sure I'll need this trick. But I'll keep it in my mind. Thanks for your answer!